# shelve module on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.4, shelve, object-persistence

I'm trying to add object-persistence to my python app. I'm currently using python 3.4 on windows.

The only module I found useful was shelve but on windows, it appears, it creates three different files rather than one: 'db.bak' ,'db.dat' and 'db.dir'.
How can I force shelve to create only single file ?
furthermore , whenever I need to open that db on read-only mode , 'db.dir' is being edited for some reason.

Does anyone know how to fix those issues ? or maybe suggest other modules that would work considering the OS and python version?

Comment: What issue do you want to solve? Maybe sqlite3 would be appropriate for you.

Comment: The read-only issue. sqlite3 wont be a fit for me as I want that db file to be dictionary oriented and serializable so I could send it over network etc.

Comment: Do you require concurrent reads from different processes?

Comment: Yes , when I tried to read-only the 'db.dir' file into my script it actually got changed meaning there wont be concurrent reading.

Comment: In addition it would very helpful if there was any way to create only a single file instead of 3